# DC analysis of a BJT circuit with base feedback

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I'm trying to analyze a bigger circuit and trying to figure out the DC voltage at the collector. I narrowed it down to this much simpler circuit, which outputs 1.379 V. I cannot seem to get the same result, so I must be doing something wrong.

I'm not sure if calling this a "base feedback" is correct, what I meant is that the base and collector share a resistor instead of the usual base divider.

What would be the steps for analyzing this kind of circuit?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: How do you analyze a BJT circuit in general? What assumptions you make for the BJT, such as beta or Vbe? The same assumptions apply here too.

Comment: +1 on what Justme said. It will be very hfe dependent.

Comment: This is a special case of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340398/collector-feedback-resistor-amplifier-q-point) (and thus an exact duplicate).

Comment: Re *"I cannot seem to get the same result"*: What result do you get? What voltage? From where? Measuring on the actual (physical) circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rough/approximate answer/method**

Call the voltage at the collector \$V_C\$ and call collector current \$I_C\$.

We can then say that \$V_C = 5 - I_C\cdot R_7\$ (assumes base current is small)

Then using the current gain of the BC547C, \$h_{FE}\$ we can say: -

$$V_C = 5 - h_{FE}\cdot I_B\cdot R_7$$

And \$I_B\$ is simply \$\dfrac{V_C - 0.7}{R_4}\$ where 0.7 is the voltage needed to roughly start to forward bias the transistor's base-emitter region.

So, putting things together we get: -

$$V_C = 5 - h_{FE}\cdot \dfrac{V_C - 0.7}{R_4}\cdot R_7$$

For a [BC547C](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/59764.pdf) transistor, \$h_{FE}\$ is about 600: -

[image]

And given the values for the two resistors we get: -

$$V_C = 5 - 600\cdot \dfrac{V_C - 0.7}{1000000}\cdot 10000$$

$$V_C = 5 - 6\cdot (V_C - 0.7)$$

$$7\cdot V_C = 5 + 4.2$$

Hence, \$V_C\$ is about 9.2/7 = 1.314 volts.

> *What would be the steps for analysing this kind of circuit?*

Well you could do what I did above or, you could use a simulator: -

[image]

The simulator estimates the collector voltage to be 1.502 volts and therein lies the difficulty in analysing single BJT amplifiers because there are assumptions made about current gain and base voltages that are probably more accurately made using a sim.

Comment: Andy, may I ask what circuit simulator is that? It has a very nice UI

Comment: micro-cap 12 (https://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip) and it's free.

Comment: I worked on this one - 
but it has only DC sources, resistors and capacitors (at this early stage): www.circuitpark.io

Comment: I've been using microcap since 2005 if I remember correctly and it now comes free with a host of libraries. A lot of EEs now prefer this package to LTSpice.

Comment: It just looks that voltage \ current label is right on the schematic. And if you can also perform continuous transient analysis (even while editing the circuit), then it's perfect really.

Comment: I would not use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your KVL equation is:

5V - (Ib + Ic) * 10k - (Ib) * 1M - 600 mV = 0

Ic = 100 * Ib; so substitute Ic above with 100 * Ib

600 mV is typical for Vbe.

Now once you obtain Ib and Ic above, to find the Collector voltage:

Vc = 5 - (Ib + IC) * 10k

Typically writing KVL and KCL equations while substituting a linear model for the transistor per its assumed state (which you verify upon obtaining the resulting currents and voltages) is a good plan. If you've had more than 1 independent source (the C-E of the transistor is like a dependent current controlled current source), superposition often helps.

(If you do superposition, you must keep dependent sources present at each iteration of the superposition).

Comment: We have [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here for much higher fidelity of the equations. There is also poor man's MathJax (subscript and superscript, `<sub></sub>` and `<sup></sup>`). The units ought to be included in the computations. Some symbols, e.g. "Ω" and "µ" can be copied [from here](https://pmortensen.eu/world/FixedStrings.php).

Comment: And 100 is the current gain?

Comment: Yes that's the relationship between Ic and Ib.